# How to set the length of a vector (in xna)

Tags: c#, vector, xna

Hey, I'm wondering if there's a function out there to set the length of an XNA framework Vector3, like in c++ it would just be VECTOR.setLength( x ). 
Either that or the basic math to do it manually would be nice :)

Comment: I can see how you can calculate the length, not setting the length.

Comment: that's the vector length in 3D, which is the magnitude of the vector.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Normalize it and then multiply it by the desired length.

```
vec = Vector3.Normalize(vec) * length;
```